# How to display error on the same page when an error is returned by a form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cgi, ibm-midrange

I have built a login form using below code.

I am using a CGI version `CGIDEV2` native to IBMi series. I am Validating the `userid` and `password` in the `flower.cgi` program. If the `userid` and `password` are validated, I am loading another `html` file to show a table. This works flawlessly.

If the `userid` and `password` are wrong, I am returning out of the program without writing anything. This results in a 500 Internal server error.

I want to capture this 500 Internal server error using javascript. I have tried using ajax but was not successful as I have limited understanding of javascript.

What could be the best way to achieve this?

```html
<form method="POST" action="/nature/flower.cgi">
  <!-- Username input -->
  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <input type="text" name="userid" id="form3Example3" class="form-control form-control-lg" style="text-transform:uppercase" placeholder="Enter a valid IBMi UserID" />
    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">IBMi UserID</label>
  </div>
  <!-- Password input -->
  <div class="form-outline mb-3">
    <input type="password" name="passwd" id="form3Example4" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter password" />
    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4">Password</label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <!-- Checkbox -->
    <div class="form-check mb-0">
      <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="form2Example3" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <a href="#!" class="text-body">Forgot password?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center text-lg-start mt-4 pt-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="padding-left: 2.5rem; padding-right: 2.5rem;">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Using Ajax. So find more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't capture an error from a URL the browser is navigating to.

The only way you could would be if you replaced the normal form submission with Ajax (in which the request is made **and** the response processed with JavaScript).

Generally speaking, if you were going to do that you would also want to rewrite the CGI program so it output structured data (e.g. as JSON) instead of semantic data (HTML).

It would not be a particularly small undertaking. You said you had tried it, which probably gives you some idea of the scope of it (i.e. far outside the scope of a Stackoverflow question).

A more sensible approach would almost certainly be to track down the cause of the 500 error and change the CGI program so it would capture it itself.

Comment: Thanks. I went with handling everything using CGI program and properly returning a HTML page from the program.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the `fetch` api in javascript can post form data to your CGI program and check for the 500 response code.  Then the web page can either display an error message or run the `form.submit()` method to actually submit the form up to the server.

Here is PHP and javascript code that simulates the whole thing. Should work similar with CGI. The key is you change the form submit button from type 'submit' to type 'button'. That way, clicking the submit button can run javascript code instead of the form being submitted to the server.

```
<?php
// site/tester/php/submit-form.php 

header("Content-type: text/html; charset:utf-8;");
?>

<?php
$userid = isset($_POST["userid"]) ? $_POST["userid"]: '' ; 
$passwd = isset($_POST["passwd"]) ? $_POST["passwd"]: '' ; 
$remember = isset($_POST["remember"]) ? $_POST["remember"]: 'off' ; 

if ( strtolower($userid) == 'alex')
{
http_response_code( 500 );
echo "$userid - invalid user name";
exit ;
}
?>

<head>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <h1>submit form demo</h1>
    </div>
</div>


</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-4">

<form method="POST" id="main-form" action="./index.php">
  <!-- Username input -->
  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" 
    class="form-control form-control-lg" 
    value="<?= $userid ?>"
    style="text-transform:uppercase" placeholder="Enter a valid IBMi UserID" />
    <label class="form-label" for="userid">IBMi UserID</label>
  </div>
  <!-- Password input -->
  <div class="form-outline mb-3">
    <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" class="form-control form-control-lg" 
    placeholder="Enter password" />
    <label class="form-label" for="passwd">Password</label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <!-- Checkbox -->
    <div class="form-check mb-0">
      <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" 
      <?= ($remember == 'on' ? 'checked' : '' ) ?>
                  name="remember" id="form2Example3" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <a href="#!" class="text-body">Forgot password?</a>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center text-lg-start mt-4 pt-2">
    <button id="login-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
            style="padding-left: 2.5rem; padding-right: 2.5rem;">
            Login</button>
  </div>

</form>    
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="login-errmsg-collapse" class="collapse row mt-3">
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">

<p id="login-errmsg">Invalid login. User name does not exist.</p>

</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row mt-3">

  <div class="col-auto">
    <p>userid: <?= $userid ?></p>
    <p>passwd: <?= $passwd ?></p>
    <p>remember: <?= $remember ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>

</body>
```

```
// ./submit-form/app.js 

// enable the submit button click handler.
{
  const elem = document.getElementById('login-button');
  elem.addEventListener('click', event =>
  {
    login_click();
  });
}

// -------------------------------- login_errmsg_show ---------------------
function login_errmsg_show( respText )
{

  // show the response message in the bootstrap collapse alert box. 
  {
    const elem = document.getElementById('login-errmsg') ;
    elem.textContent = respText ;
  }

  const myCollapse = document.getElementById('login-errmsg-collapse')
  const bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
    toggle: false
  });
  bsCollapse.show( ) ;
}

// -------------------------------- login_click -------------------
async function login_click()
{
  const elem = document.getElementById('main-form');
  if (elem)
  {
    const {respText, status} = await webpage_post( ) ;
    if ( status != '500')
    {
      elem.submit();
    }
    else 
    {
      login_errmsg_show( respText ) ;
    }
  }
}

// --------------------------------- webpage_post -----------------------
async function webpage_post( )
{
  const userid = document.getElementById('userid').value ;
  const passwd = document.getElementById('passwd').value ;
  const remember = 'on' ;
 
  const url = "./index.php";

  const params = { userid, passwd, remember } ;
  const query = object_toQueryString(params);

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: query
  });

  const respText = await response.text();
  const status = response.status ;
  console.log( respText ) ;
  return {respText, status} ;
}

// ------------------------- object_toQueryString ------------------------
function object_toQueryString(obj)
{
  const qs = Object.keys(obj)
    .map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]))
    .join('&');
  return qs;
}
```